# Random assembly / application name everytime the applicaiton is launched VB.NET code

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to figure out a way to make it so everytime i launch my application it renames the application to a random string.

My application is in VB.NET

This is my frmLogin.vb (i put the code inside same class as login, since login is my start window, didnt know where else to put it)
Code:

```
    Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
    Const REGISTRY_KEY As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Prototype"
    Const REGISTY_FIRSTRUN As String = "FirstRun"
    Const REGISTY_LASTNAME As String = "LastName"
    Dim RandomTitle As String = RandomString(RandomShit.[Next](5, 15)) & ".exe"

    Try

        If Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(REGISTRY_KEY, REGISTY_FIRSTRUN, 0)) = 0 Then
            Console.Title = RandomTitle
            Dim TempPath As String = Convert.ToString(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(REGISTRY_KEY, REGISTY_LASTNAME, 0))

            If AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName <> "RandomShit.exe" Then
                File.Delete("RandomShit.exe")
            End If

            If File.Exists(TempPath) Then
                File.Delete(TempPath)
            End If

            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(REGISTRY_KEY, REGISTY_FIRSTRUN, 1, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(REGISTRY_KEY, REGISTY_LASTNAME, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
        End If

    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: @what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Well i want it so everytime i launch the .exe it changes the exe's name to randomly generated string

Comment: what is problem?

Comment: It doesnt work! It doesnt change the applications name at all!

Comment: where is code of renaming?

Comment: I dont have one, thats why i was asking on here, Cause i found that part of code online.

Comment: do you need code in vb.net  or c#??

Comment: I need it in VB.net

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether below code completely satisfied your requirement. I hope below works for you to rename an executable file:

```
File.Move(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName), "randomstring.exe"))
```

Comment: dayum this is working. Any idea why this this is not trowing an `system.io.ioexception file used by another process` error ? I mean, the application is renaming itself while running, I'd expected an error.

Comment: lets give it a try..and see what happens

Comment: I just have tried that, and it's working, I'm baffled.

Comment: Where to add it

Comment: Add in start up class

Comment: In frmLogin.vb?

Comment: If it is your bootstrap then you can do it

Comment: What? I dont have a bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap means main class which kickoff application

Comment: My application start window is frmLogin.vb

Comment: I inserted the code i provided here at first in the frmLogin.vb

Comment: IT DID NOT WORK!

Comment: check into directory. it must change as i ran code it works for me

Comment: Upload your code on pastebin, heres mine: https://pastebin.com/Y8cQc73d

Comment: I had just onle code which I shared nothing else after rename exe is running and when you navigate to exe folder ,you will see exe name changed

Comment: Where did you add it? To the main class? in frmlogin.vb?

Comment: And how is the name randomly generated?

Comment: I want it to be randomly generated using this code:      Public Shared Function RandomString(ByVal length As Integer) As String
        Const Chars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw"
        Return New String(Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, length).[Select](Function(s) s(RandomShit.[Next](s.Length))).ToArray())
    End Function

Comment: use random generator